# Deploying a Django site with sensitive code on a host

Tags: django, web-hosting

I've been developing a site with sensitive (i.e. proprietary) code on my local machine, testing it using apache2, and I'm finally going to be getting it setup with a web host. I'm a bit wary because of the "Where should this code live?" note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) in the Django Tutorial:

> Where should this code live?
>
> If your background is in plain old PHP (with no use of modern frameworks), you’re probably used to putting code under the Web server’s document root (in a place such as /var/www). With Django, you don’t do that. It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web server’s document root, because it risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web. That’s not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as /home/mycode.

My host told me that I'll be given a /home/ directory, and that the site will live in /home/www. I'm trying to emulate this directory structure on my end before I send everything to him to make sure it goes as smoothly as possible. My question is, if I want all my code to live outside of the /www directory (per the Django tutorial recommendation above), what actually goes inside the /www directory?

My development directory structure is basically this:

```
project
    db
    app1
    app2
    mysite (contains settings.py, wsgi.py, etc.)
    static
    templates (contains my base.html, and custom templates for admin, etc.)
```

Where app1 and app2 are Django apps I've developed to plug into mysite. So what folders / files need to go in the home/www directory, and what can safely live in home/mycode?

Comment: potentially nothing, though you'd most likely put your static files in there and allow Apache to serve them directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static and media (user-uploaded) folders, `robots.txt` etc. should be in the `www` directory. Basically any file that is directly served by your webserver and not through Django. Other files should live outside of this directory.

Your webserver should point all requests that are not found in the `www` directory towards your wsgi application, which doesn't need the code to be accessible by an url.

The reason for this is that your webserver does not execute the code in a python file, in contrast to php files. If your code lived in your web root, people could read your settings files by just going to `example.com/src/settings.py`. Images, plain html/text files and javascript should be read, but any code that should be executed should live outside your web root. Django will execute the files and generate the response that a user should actually see.

Comment: When you say "Images, plain html/text files and javascript should be read, but any code that should be executed should live outside your web root" I'm a bit confused. My template directories (which include javascript in the html headers) are all outside the www folder as well. Is that ok, or will they not load properly? I assume Django will still serve them as if they were inside the www directory?

Comment: @GravityGrave With 'files that should be read' I mean files that should be read and served as-is by the webserver (nginx, apache). Template files are read and then processed by Django, not directly by the webserver. These can (and probably should) live outside of the webroot.